# Permutations and indexes, python

Tags: python, algorithm, list, permutation, combinatorics

I create a list of all permutations of lets say 0,1,2

```
perm = list(itertools.permutations([0,1,2]))
```

This is used for accessing indexes in another list in that specific order. Every time a index is accessed it is popped.
When an element is popped, the elements with indexes higher than the popped elements index will shift one position down. This means that if I want to pop from my list by indexes [0,1,2] it will result in an index error, since index 2 will not exist when I reach it. [0,1,2] should therefor be popped in order [0,0,0].

more examples is

```
[0,2,1] = [0,1,0]
[2,0,1] = [2,0,0]
[1,2,0] = [1,1,0]
```

right now this is being handled through a series of checks, my question is if anyone knows a smart way to turn the list of lists generated by itertools into the desired list:

```
[(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0)]
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (2, 0, 0), (2, 1, 0)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply iterate through each tuple, and decrement the indexes of each subsequent index that is greater than that element:

```
l=[(0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1), (1, 0, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0)]
def lower_idxs(lst):
    new_row = list(lst)
    for i, val in enumerate(new_row):
        for j in xrange(i+1, len(new_row)):
            if new_row[i] < new_row[j]:
                new_row[j] -= 1
    return new_row

print [lower_idxs(x) for x in l]
```

will print out

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0]]
```

Here is a fancier one-liner based on Randy C's solution:

```
print [tuple(y-sum(v<y for v in x[:i]) for i,y in enumerate(x)) for x in l]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-liner for it (assuming your list is l):

```
[v-sum(v>v2 for v2 in l[:k]) for k, v in enumerate(l)]
```